# How can I remove all the \n characters from all the list elements in list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I remove all the `\n` from all the elements of this list?

```
>>> a = [['cfg', '8\n', '4', ('02030800', '02050\n800', '02070800', '02090800')], ['ml', '5\n', '2', ('0000\n0000',)]]
```

I tried this, but did not work.

```
>>> t = map(lambda s: s.strip(), a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: What do/don’t you understand from the error message? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution which replaces the newlines in the lists *and* the tuples. You can just let it pass the tuples if you want them to remain immutable.

```
a = [['cfg', '8\n', '4', ('02030800', '02050\n800', '02070800', '02090800')], ['ml', '5\n', '2', ('0000\n0000',)]]

def remove_newline_from_lists(args):
    for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        if isinstance(arg, tuple):
            args[i] = tuple([tuple_elem.replace("\n", "") for tuple_elem in arg])
        elif isinstance(arg, list):
            remove_newline_from_lists(arg)
        elif isinstance(arg, str):
            args[i] = arg.replace("\n", "")
        else:
            continue

remove_newline_from_lists(a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace('\n','')`

```
a = [['cfg', '8\n', '4', ('02030800', '02050\n800', '02070800', '02090800')], ['ml', '5\n', '2', ('0000\n0000',)]]
a2 = []
for k in a:
    for r in k:
        if isinstance(r,str):
            a2.append(r.replace('\n',''))
        else:
            a2.append( [ x.replace('\n','') for x in r ]  )
```

Output:

```
['cfg', '8', '4', ['02030800', '02050800', '02070800', '02090800'], 'ml', '5', '2', ['00000000']]
```

Comment: @GinoMempin some of the newlines are not at the end.

Comment: Ahhh, I missed the `\n` that are not at the end.